# What is the difference between ECC/Non-ECC and Buffered/Unbuffered?

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard

About RAM for laptops I did realize that is available

- ECC
- Non-ECC
- Buffered
- Unbuffered

It according with:

- [Kingston Technology KVR16LS11/8 8GB 1600MHz DDR3L (PC3-12800) 1.35V **Non-ECC** CL11 SODIMM Intel Laptop Memory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CQ35HBQ)
- [A-Tech 4GB DDR2 800MHz SODIMM PC2-6400 1.8V CL6 200-Pin **Non-ECC Unbuffered** Laptop RAM Memory Upgrade Module](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00C53AZQY)

That options appears on [newegg](https://www.newegg.com/) it for [Laptop Memory](https://www.newegg.com/Laptop-Memory/SubCategory/ID-381) (only about `ECC`) and [Server Memory](https://www.newegg.com/Server-Memory/SubCategory/ID-541) (about `ECC` and `Buffered/Registered`)

**Question(s)**

- What is the difference between `ECC`/`Non-ECC` and `Buffered`/`Unbuffered`?

And what is better for each pair? and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECC Memory can correct small errors (bit flips), this is typically used for applications where data integrity is important.

Buffered memory can help prevent errors by placing a register between the controller and memory modules, again, this is typically used for applications where data integrity is important.

In simple terms, The buffer reduces errors, and ECC corrects them.

If you simply want to upgrade your laptop, you generally wont need ECC/buffered memory. The chance of bit flips occurring is extermely low and often wont result in any unusual behavior.

Comment: One can theorize about this, but in general one could expect to see more errors in older hard-used equipment. When in personal (private) use, it is often better to replace the hardware when problems arise - a three to five year "upgrade schedule" is often "good" - as software has a tendency to outgrow the hardware in such a time frame.

Comment: It should be noted that this type of ECC memory does NOT correect small errors. ECC memory simply has more bits, so external circuitry (if available, which it is not on typical consumer hardware) is required., ECC memory without this circuitry will usually act like non-ECC memory.

Comment: Similarly, buffered memory is usually slower, so if both types are supported, unbuffered is typically faster. The buffers primary purpose is not to reduce bit errors, but ti reduce electrical load. When RAM and board are in-spec, no additional errors will be introduced when using unbuffered memory.